# How to sync two LightSlider sliders together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, jquery-ui-slider

I am trying to sync two LightSlider sliders together on a page using the asNavFor option, but I'm having trouble getting them to work together. I have followed the documentation on the LightSlider website, but my sliders are not syncing.

```
// HTML
<div class="slider1">
  <div><img src="image1.jpg" alt="Image 1"></div>
  <div><img src="image2.jpg" alt="Image 2"></div>
  <div><img src="image3.jpg" alt="Image 3"></div>
</div>

<div class="slider2">
  <div><img src="thumb1.jpg" alt="Thumbnail 1"></div>
  <div><img src="thumb2.jpg" alt="Thumbnail 2"></div>
  <div><img src="thumb3.jpg" alt="Thumbnail 3"></div>
</div>

// JavaScript
$(".slider1").lightSlider({
  asNavFor: ".slider2",
  item: 1,
  loop: true,
  slideMargin: 0,
  adaptiveHeight: true
});

$(".slider2").lightSlider({
  asNavFor: ".slider1",
  item: 3,
  loop: true,
  slideMargin: 0,
  adaptiveHeight: true,
  vertical: true,
  verticalHeight: 80,
  vThumbWidth: 50,
  thumbItem: 9,
  thumbMargin: 4,
  slideMargin: 0
});
```

When I run this code, the two sliders are not syncing together. How can I fix this issue. Is there any way? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you add some link to the lightSlider you are using and/or the documentation you are checking? I can't find any reference to asNavFor in https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightslider/blob/master/src/js/lightslider.js

Comment: I have done this based on assumptions. Is there any way that I can synchronous two slider together

Comment: I don't see any sync mode in the lightSlider function. If you could make both sliders use the same configuration, you could try using the same class in both and a single function call.